# Mouse pointer stops the slide transition in fwslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a slider called `fwslider` and when the mouse pointer get into the slider that will stop the slide transition and when the mouse pointer get away from the slider the slide transition continues. I need to get rid of this effect. What is the attribute should I change?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue? Seems that the fwslider demo doesn't have this behaviour by default..

Comment: The demo also has that one. I need to stop it

Comment: This demo: http://ctmaloney.github.io/fwslider/ doesn't halt when I hover my cursor over it.

Comment: Furthermore: I can't find anything in the source-code of fwslider that will pause on hover. Maybe it's helpful if you post your code.

Comment: http://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/voyage-flat-travel-responsive-web-template/ I used the fwslider which used in this template. It is also a fwslider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this script after the slider is initialized

```
$(_0x69b9[62]).unbind('mouseover').unbind('mouseleave')
```

the value of `_0x69b9[62]` is `#fwslider .slide_content`